# curl request does not accept a password containing "@" for a url with HTTP basic authentication

Tags: linux, http, curl, basic-authentication

As we know that a curl request for a url that is protected by basic authentication can be made by using a format like this curl  -v http://username: password@xyz.com . But i have observed that passing credentials like this only works if password does not have a "@" itself.  For example If my request is  curl -v http://user01:helloworld@xyz.com it will work . But if it is curl -v http://user01:hello@world@xyz.com  , it fails . How can we make the first @ to be understood as a password, as currently i think @ is taken as a conventional delimiter before passing credentials, and therefore request gets confused as to what is the password . Any thoughts on this, or am i missing anything ?

Comment: Have you tried to URL-encode it?

Comment: I am talking about a raw request using curl on a Linux instance , not through code using encoding libraries .

Comment: I know, why not try it?

Comment: The more obvious choice being -u.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx i know may be i can accomplish through that code . It is just an observation for which i seek answer for . Suppose i define a cronjob url on Linux that requires basic authentication and password strictly contain a @ character , then how could we run that cronjob , if request fails to interpret the credentials . Suppose i call a url in cronjob using sudo wget , we will face same situation . Any points on that ??

Comment: I'm sorry , is -u is a switch in curl ?????

Comment: Yes, to pass the username and optionally the password, meaning you could remove it from the target url. I just don't have any appropriate server to test against.

Comment: Ya meanwhile i also came across some example that pass credentials separately . Thanks to you, wasn't thinking in terms of url encoding perspective, as i took it as code based approach !! Guess , it will work !

Comment: While I do expect the same, do let me know or post an answer yourself.

Comment: Sure , will update once i test .

Answer (score 1):

Use -u which defaults to basic auth

```
   -u, --user <user:password>
          Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication. Overrides -n, --netrc and  --netrc-
          optional.

          If you simply specify the user name, curl will prompt for a password.

          The user name and passwords are split up on the first colon, which makes it impossible to use a colon in
          the user name with this option. The password can, still.
```

Possibly even better would be to define your passwords in the netrc file and then avoid passwords on the command line altogether.